# Is it possible for JavaScript front-end web to programmatically press a sequence of keys that will hit the OS?

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have a modem that will initiate a phone call if the copy command is run. And that is currently working when I run this:

```
document.execCommand("copy")
```

The problem is that if I have the modem use the copy command then a phone call is attempted every time I copy something.

So I wanted to use a key press sequence that isn't a shortcut like ctrl + q. The modem can be programmed to respond to ctrl + q.

Is it possible to have JavaScript programmatically press ctrl + q and have it register outside of the browser so that the modem sees it?

Comment: in a word - no.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager But question asks specifically for "Javascript front-end web"